# In the sentence "Glory is better than fame", is "fame" a predicate nominative?

Tags: comparative, case

With the intent of translating this sentence to Latin, what case is the word "fame"?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The title and the text ask different questions. Can you elaborate on what you really want to know and (which is very important) what your own thoughts are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your title you ask if "fame" is a predicate nominative, and the answer to that question is **no**. A predicate nominative involves the linking of a noun with the subject via a copula (usually a form of "to be" or "to become").

Based on the body of your question, I suspect that your real question is what case would best be used to translate *fame*. The answer is that you have two options.

1. **Same case as compared noun = nominative**

   > Gloria melior est quam fama.
2. **Ablative of comparison**

   > Gloria famā melior est.

The two are both equally valid, though the ablative is often avoided in cases where ambiguity could arise. In this particular case, I would probably favor the first option because my ear isn't sensitive enough to vowel quantity to intuitively understand the second when spoken.

Comment: To add to this, the two things being compared with *quam* always take the same case; ergo, *gloria melior est quam fama* but *puto gloriam meliorem esse quam famam.*